# how to send image using ajax post?

Tags: jquery

Is this possible to send  image or video file through jquery ajax post method?yes or no?

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "url?json",
            data: {image:},
            success: function (o) {

            },
            dataType:"json"
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Uploading a file need a full postback.

You can simulate an ajax call posting to a hidden iFrame (so your page don't change).
Then checking the content of the iFrame using jquery/javascript you can see if the upload was successful and do a refresh of certain part of your screen.

**If you are using ASP.NET MVC3 or MVC4 here is an example (I'm using this):**
http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2011/11/16/AJAX-File-Uploads-with-jQuery-and-MVC-3.aspx

**If you want a more generic way of doing it in JS:**
http://tips.itliveweb.com/ajax/upload-image-using-iframe-javascript-ajax.html